# Selected dropdown value cleared on certain key press

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I came up with a strange behaviour of PF's selectonemenu component. When I select a value from a dropdown list and press one of the following keys (when there's a focus on a dropdown): PrtScr, Insert, Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock, most of function keys,... a dropdown value is cleared (and 'change' event gets called).

Why does this happen and how to get rid of that 'key binding'?

EDIT:

Found some JS code in PrimeFaces source that does key binding (see below), I guess this is the code that causes dropdown value to be cleared.

```
bindKeyEvents: function() {
    var a = this;
    this.focusInput.on("keydown.ui-selectonemenu", function(d) {
        var c = $.ui.keyCode,
            b = d.which;
        switch (b) {
            case c.UP:
            case c.LEFT:
                a.highlightPrev(d);
                break;
            case c.DOWN:
            case c.RIGHT:
                a.highlightNext(d);
                break;
            case c.ENTER:
            case c.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                a.handleEnterKey(d);
                break;
            case c.TAB:
                a.handleTabKey();
                break;
            case c.ESCAPE:
                a.handleEscapeKey(d);
                break
        }
    }).on("keyup.ui-selectonemenu", function(g) {
        var f = $.ui.keyCode,
            d = g.which;
        switch (d) {
            case f.UP:
            case f.LEFT:
            case f.DOWN:
            case f.RIGHT:
            case f.ENTER:
            case f.NUMPAD_ENTER:
            case f.TAB:
            case f.ESCAPE:
            case f.SPACE:
            case f.HOME:
            case f.PAGE_DOWN:
            case f.PAGE_UP:
            case f.END:
            case f.DELETE:
            case 16:
            case 17:
            case 18:
            case 224:
                break;
            default:
                var i = $(this).val(),
                    c = null,
                    h = g.metaKey || g.ctrlKey || g.shiftKey;
                if (!h) {
                    clearTimeout(a.searchTimer);
                    c = a.options.filter(function() {
                        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(i.toLowerCase()) === 0
                    });
                    if (c.length) {
                        var b = a.items.eq(c.index());
                        if (a.panel.is(":hidden")) {
                            a.selectItem(b)
                        } else {
                            a.highlightItem(b);
                            PrimeFaces.scrollInView(a.itemsWrapper, b)
                        }
                    }
                    a.searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                        a.focusInput.val("")
                    }, 1000)
                }
                break
        }
    })
}
```

If I understand that code correctly, it's the following part that causes my problem, right?

```
a.searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    a.focusInput.val("")
                }
```

Comment: I can reproduce this in the showcase. Please check the primefaces javascript source of the component to see if it can be explained by something in there.

Comment: @Kukeltje I did some editing on my question based on source code check as you suggested. Can you confirm that I found the cause of my problem? If so, do you know what is the purpose of that key binding?